# SSRS column grouping..blank rows issue

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-grouping

I am trying to build a SSRS report.

I need a report like this.

```
TopGroup_Val1
  SecondGroup_Val1
    Deatils{Col1..Col2..Col3.........}
    .........................
  SecondGroup_Val2
    Col1..Col2..Col3.........
    .........................
 TopGroup_Val2
    SecondGroup_Val1
    Col1..Col2..Col3.........
```

For each Top group, there can be multiple second group elements. For each combination of top group and secong group, there can be multiple rows of data.

I tried using colmn grouping. But I got a report like this 
[image: report]

```
   In the above picture, TopGroup is Company. Second group is Dept.
```

Currently DB has one Company with 3 depts and each dept with one employee each. The report has three pages. second page shows second dept of the company with one row of data and two blank rows.
Design page looks as below.
[image: Design page]
How can I achieve what I am looking for? Why is the data going to multiple pages even if I have only 3 rows of data? Why are blank rows coming? Please share the info.

Answer (score -1):

Remove page break at the end by employee